# How to get the value of a variable that's deep in the source code (C++)? (eg. value of stage_sum in haar.cpp, OpenCV)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'd like to get a value from a variable that's located deeply in the source code of the OpenCV library. Specifically, I'm trying to print out the value of stage_sum from the file haar.cpp. My starting point, facedetect.cpp, calls the method detectMultiScale, which then calls the function cvHaarDetectObjects, which calls cvHaarDetectObjectsForROC etc., until it finally reaches the function cvRunHaarClassifierCascadeSum, where stage_sum is calculated.

Is there a way I could get the value out to facedetect.cpp easily, without changing the declarations of all the preceding functions/methods, headers etc.? Simply trying to cout or printf the value directly in the source code hasn't given any results.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Sounds like you need a debugger.

Comment: At which platform (Windows, Linux, Android, iOS) do you use this library?

Comment: If this question has been successfully answered, consider selecting the official answer by clicking on the checkbox near it. If not, consider adding your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

One option is simply to use a debugger.

However, if you want to do this programatically (i.e. access the variable as part of your application code), then unless the variable is exposed in the library's public interface, there are two options available:

- Modify the library's source code, and recompile it.
- Resort to undefined-behaviour (fiddling around with the raw bytes that make up an object, etc.).

Comment: I 'make' the library after every change (I'm under Ubuntu), I suppose that this falls under recompiling?
And I don't understand what exactly undefined-behaviour means, are you reffering to accesing the value via some kind of pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Just to point the obvious, adding a `std::cout()` or `printf()` call inside *haar.cpp* won't do the trick. You need to **recompile** OpenCV for this changes to take effect and then **reinstall** the libraries on your system.

Comment: in case of android platform, it possibly will not help as by default `stdout` and `stderr` are redirected to `dev/null`, that's why I asked about the platform in comment to the question.

Comment: The platform in question is Ubuntu, and I 'make' the whole library after every change (I suppose that I don't have to reinstall it as well?).

Comment: @Alex Then write the output to a file instead of stdin/stderr. :P

Comment: @kolarek you have to reinstall it when you rebuild it! `make install`

Comment: God, I'm such an idiot! I'll try this right away. Thank you very much!

Comment: @karlphillip yes, but what is the shortest way to do it from the OpenCV source point of view?

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure I understand your question. Which possible *ways* do you want to compare?

Comment: @karlphillip I mean how can I inside OpenCV redirect stdout to file? Something tells me that it must be done at application level, not a library level.

Comment: @Alex One can always use the [LD_PRELOAD trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick). Assuming Linux, of course (which is the scope of the question).

Comment: @karlphillip Actually, I mean android platform (see the first comment for the answer), but it is not actually topic of this question. Anyway, thanks.